# Should I remove or cover existing, damaged crawl space encapsulation plastic?

Tags: crawlspace, encapsulation

I live in Toronto, Ontario, Canada.

I purchased crawl space encapsulation poly (10 mil plastic sheeting) for a 16 x 20 ft area. The 6 mil poly that is currently there has failed and is torn in a few places.

Should I remove it completely or can I add the 10 mil poly on top of the 6 mil? Will the extra mil help?

Comment: The description of the product sounds like it was copied directly from the Amazon listing. Why is it that you're putting in 10mil plastic instead of/in addition to the 6mil that's already there? Has the 6mil failed (is it torn up), or do you believe you need something thicker than 6mil, and if so, why? Please [edit] this info into your question.

Comment: Much better, thx!